# Quantifying Dependency in Chi Squared Test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, independence, contingency-tables

I am running a Chi Squared test on nominal values and this is the contingency table.

```
            mac     windows All
            
dislike     1590    1925    3515
like        904     1637    2541
All         2494    3562    6056
```

Expected values are:

```
[[1447 2067]
 [1046 1494]]
```

p-value is significantly less than 0.05 so we reject the null hypothesis and we conclude there is dependency in OS and the like/dislike. We also decide Mac users are more likely to dislike than windows users from the difference in expected values and observed values.

From this I want to quantify how likely Mac users are to dislike than Windows users.
Does the simple calculation of

```
(observed_dislike_mac - expected_dislike_mac) / expected_dislike_mac = 
(1590 - 1447) / 1447 = 
0.09
```

tell us that mac users are 10% more likely to dislike than they are supposed to?

Also,

```
(expected_like_mac - observed_like_mac) / expected_like_mac = 
(1046 - 904) / 1046 = 
0.13
```

mean Mac users are 13% less likely to like than expected?

Finally, how do you calculate how likely are mac users to dislike than windows users? Does,

```
If you are a mac user how likely you to dislike = 
1590 / 2494 = 
63%

If you are a win user how likely you to dislike = 
1925 / 3562 = 
54%
```

say that mac users are 9% more likely to dislike?

Comment: I don't believe this answers the questions in the body text (hence it's a comment rather than an answer), but it is relevant to the issue raised in the title: one common measure of dependence in a 2x2 contingency table is the odds-ratio. E.g. see the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds_ratio#Definition_and_basic_properties

Answer (score 1):

The best way is maybe to complement yout table of counts with a table with percents (which corresponds to your calculations in the last paragraph).

```r
tab
         mac windows
dislike 1590    1925
like     904    1637
```

Columnpercents are obtained (here in R) by

```r
prop.table(tab, 2)
              mac   windows
dislike 0.6375301 0.5404267
like    0.3624699 0.4595733
```

and this is how you could present it.